# Alternative Sports in Sweden

Tags: sweden

I'm moving to Uppsala in a month or so -- I was wondering what was available in terms of alternative team sports (aside from the usual football, hockey, etc.)

In the UK I play Octopush, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There should be plenty. I lived there some years ago and there were a lot of clubs. If you'll be in the university, the options are even better. As for Octopush I'm not sure, there used to be an active underwater rugby club but I have no updated information.

Some clubs (including underwater rugby) listed here. It's partly in Swedish, but the list is rather self-explanatory:
http://195.178.187.141/forening/default.aspx